# Unable to connect MongoDB with basic example

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoose, pymongo

I am using the example from the MongoDB website. here is the link to the example. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/pymongo/

Here is the code in my app.py file.

```
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
from pymongo.server_api import ServerApi

# Replace the placeholder with your Atlas connection string
uri = "<connection string>"

# Set the Stable API version when creating a new client
client = MongoClient(uri, server_api=ServerApi('1'))
                          
# Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I have replaced `"connection string"` with my connection string from my MongoDB account. I have changed username and password to the credentials from my account.
Here is the error message I get:

```
bad auth : authentication failed, full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : 
authentication failed', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

Any tips to resolve this?

I expected the code to run after running python app.py

Comment: Is your Mongo db setup to allow connections from your current IP? Check the Network Access settings in Mongo.

Comment: Is your URI validated by [`pymongo.uri_parser.parse_uri`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/uri_parser.html)?  If you have any _"special"_ characters in `username` or `password`, they need to be encoded/escaped properly.

Comment: Show us your connection string. Did you specify the authenticationDatabase? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470